# Populate same value to several rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to make dataframe, where custom function calculate point of control every day at 00:00:00 time. I want to have that value for every hour during that day, buy unfortunately I have no idea how to make it work.

this is code to calculate POC:

```
df['poc'] = np.where(df.index.time == datetime.time(0, 0), MP(df), np.NaN)
```

and this is dataframe i got:

```
df.tail(25)

Open    High    Low Close   Volume  time_shift  Day poc
d                               
2020-04-23 21:00:00 1.07824 1.07832 1.07650 1.07783 3473.3799   1   Thu NaN
2020-04-23 22:00:00 1.07786 1.07860 1.07756 1.07788 8224.6172   1   Thu NaN
2020-04-23 23:00:00 1.07788 1.07807 1.07776 1.07802 2160.2749   1   Thu NaN
2020-04-24 00:00:00 1.07802 1.07803 1.07740 1.07748 2582.1899   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 01:00:00 1.07747 1.07795 1.07616 1.07666 9285.9004   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 02:00:00 1.07665 1.07698 1.07635 1.07668 6933.2798   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 03:00:00 1.07670 1.07749 1.07663 1.07716 4954.4902   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 04:00:00 1.07716 1.07718 1.07667 1.07714 2706.1001   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 05:00:00 1.07714 1.07743 1.07691 1.07717 3514.6699   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 06:00:00 1.07716 1.07716 1.07608 1.07635 5639.1099   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 07:00:00 1.07635 1.07666 1.07379 1.07385 12774.6904  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 08:00:00 1.07386 1.07515 1.07273 1.07409 17478.3398  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 09:00:00 1.07411 1.07592 1.07332 1.07561 16367.4004  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 10:00:00 1.07563 1.07683 1.07498 1.07657 12247.1602  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 11:00:00 1.07657 1.07985 1.07621 1.07855 11799.6699  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 12:00:00 1.07855 1.08061 1.07773 1.07934 14338.0498  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 13:00:00 1.07934 1.08102 1.07906 1.08033 17819.3691  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 14:00:00 1.08033 1.08081 1.07847 1.07971 16529.6094  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 15:00:00 1.07968 1.08201 1.07897 1.08139 20221.3594  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 16:00:00 1.08139 1.08143 1.07942 1.07972 13310.6201  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 17:00:00 1.07974 1.08025 1.07866 1.07885 12209.4297  1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 18:00:00 1.07885 1.07953 1.07847 1.07943 7231.2798   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 19:00:00 1.07943 1.08011 1.07908 1.07979 7819.2300   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 20:00:00 1.07978 1.08134 1.07970 1.08113 5934.1802   1   Fri NaN
2020-04-24 21:00:00 1.08114 1.08301 1.08084 1.08245 6193.3599   1   Fri NaN
```

So in this case I would like to have that 1.08139 for each row until I get new value next day at 00:00:00.

I tried also:

```
df['poc'] = np.where(df.index.time == datetime.time(0, 0), MP(df), df['poc'].shift(1))
```

but that gave me some random values for poc instead...

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  time_shift  Day poc
d                               
2020-04-23 21:00:00 1.07824 1.07832 1.07650 1.07783 3473.3799   1   Thu 1.08139
2020-04-23 22:00:00 1.07786 1.07860 1.07756 1.07788 8224.6172   1   Thu 1.08139
2020-04-23 23:00:00 1.07788 1.07807 1.07776 1.07802 2160.2749   1   Thu 1.08139
2020-04-24 00:00:00 1.07802 1.07803 1.07740 1.07748 2582.1899   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 01:00:00 1.07747 1.07795 1.07616 1.07666 9285.9004   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 02:00:00 1.07665 1.07698 1.07635 1.07668 6933.2798   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 03:00:00 1.07670 1.07749 1.07663 1.07716 4954.4902   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 04:00:00 1.07716 1.07718 1.07667 1.07714 2706.1001   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 05:00:00 1.07714 1.07743 1.07691 1.07717 3514.6699   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 06:00:00 1.07716 1.07716 1.07608 1.07635 5639.1099   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 07:00:00 1.07635 1.07666 1.07379 1.07385 12774.6904  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 08:00:00 1.07386 1.07515 1.07273 1.07409 17478.3398  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 09:00:00 1.07411 1.07592 1.07332 1.07561 16367.4004  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 10:00:00 1.07563 1.07683 1.07498 1.07657 12247.1602  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 11:00:00 1.07657 1.07985 1.07621 1.07855 11799.6699  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 12:00:00 1.07855 1.08061 1.07773 1.07934 14338.0498  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 13:00:00 1.07934 1.08102 1.07906 1.08033 17819.3691  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 14:00:00 1.08033 1.08081 1.07847 1.07971 16529.6094  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 15:00:00 1.07968 1.08201 1.07897 1.08139 20221.3594  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 16:00:00 1.08139 1.08143 1.07942 1.07972 13310.6201  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 17:00:00 1.07974 1.08025 1.07866 1.07885 12209.4297  1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 18:00:00 1.07885 1.07953 1.07847 1.07943 7231.2798   1   Fri 1.08139
2020-04-24 19:00:00 1.07943 1.08011 1.07908 1.07979 7819.2300   1   Fri 1.07855
2020-04-24 20:00:00 1.07978 1.08134 1.07970 1.08113 5934.1802   1   Fri 1.07855
2020-04-24 21:00:00 1.08114 1.08301 1.08084 1.08245 6193.3599   1   Fri 1.08139
```

I tried everything that I found on google but nothing worked. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your output

```
df['poc'] = np.where(df.index.time == datetime.time(0, 0), MP(df), np.NaN)

df['poc']=df['poc'].ffill()
```